# Add Index to Item in Wordpress Gallery

Tags: filters, shortcode, jquery, hooks, gallery

I'm creating a gallery of images using the `[gallery]` shortcode and Jetpack's tiled gallery feature. When the user clicks on an image I'm triggering a carousel (Owl Carousel) with `carousel.trigger( 'to.owl.carousel', [ item_id, 0 ] )`. The problem that I have is that I need to feed the trigger an index in order to have it jump to the correct item. I've previously done this by using jQuery `index()` but that won't work with the tiled gallery because items are nested inside rows.

What I need to do is add a `data-index` property to each item in the tiled gallery which I can then have correspond to the index in the carousel. Is there a way in which I can filter the gallery shortcode output in order to add this attribute as it loops through the images?

Off topic but an alternative solution might be leveraging `index()` to index the items regardless of their nested row structure, like indexing `.item` elements in relation to the parent of parent of parent container. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved the issue by looping through all of the items by class and indexing them with a data attribute.

```
$( '.tiled-gallery').each(function(){

    var i = 0;

    $(this).find('.tiled-gallery-item').each(function(){

        $(this).attr( 'data-index', i );

        i++;
    })
})
```